# Understanding behind the scenes of Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I would like to understand the internals of Entity framework like how query is constructed, when query is fired against the database and optimizations that Entity framework does. Please point me to any reference link/tutorial/video or any kind reference that gives me insights of Entity Framework.
     Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you should know EF is open source.

You will sertainly found your answers in the [code](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/).

PS: you can even step by step...

Comment: It's really difficult to step into such a large framework without any layer description at all. I think he is asking for that. You can spend million hours in investigations that you will never use. So for me it will be interesting to hear about the ef layers and abstractions.